# Why even use *DB.exec() or prepared statements in Golang?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, go, prepared-statement

I'm using golang with Postgresql.

It says [here](http://go-database-sql.org/retrieving.html) that for operations that do not return rows (insert, delete, update) we should use `exec()`

> If a function name includes Query, it is designed to ask a question of the database, and will return a set of rows, even if it’s empty. Statements that don’t return rows should not use Query functions; they should use Exec().

Then it says [here](http://go-database-sql.org/prepared.html):

> Go creates prepared statements for you under the covers. A simple db.Query(sql, param1, param2), for example, works by preparing the sql, then executing it with the parameters and finally closing the statement.

If **`query()` uses under the covers prepared statements** why should I even bother using prepared statements?

Comment: Its a choice like you can create a custom query or you can use already built-in functionality. Prepared statements give more control on how you execute the query. Also you can close the statement after you're done. It gives you more control then running `db.Query()`

Comment: You use explicitly prepared statements for queries that you want to run repeatedly. You don't have to prepare the same query over and over again.

Comment: for safety measure.

Extra steps to avoid sql injection, there could one of the project developer that just put input from web to a query string.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

#### "Why even use db.Exec()":

It's true that you can use `db.Exec` and `db.Query` interchangeably to execute the same sql statements however the two methods return different types of results. If implemented by the driver the result returned from `db.Exec` can tell you how many rows were affected by the query, while `db.Query` will return the rows object instead.

For example let's say you want to execute a `DELETE` statement and you want to know how many rows were deleted by it. You can do it either the proper way:

```
res, err := db.Exec(`DELETE FROM my_table WHERE expires_at = $1`, time.Now())
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

numDeleted, err := res.RowsAffected()
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
print(numDeleted)
```

or the more verbose and objectively costlier way:

```
rows, err := db.Query(`DELETE FROM my_table WHERE expires_at = $1 RETURNING *`, time.Now())
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
defer rows.Close()

var numDelete int
for rows.Next() {
    numDeleted += 1
}
if err := rows.Err(); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
print(numDeleted)
```

There's a 3rd way you could do this with a combination of postgres CTEs, `SELECT COUNT`, `db.QueryRow` and `row.Scan` but I don't think an example is necessary to show how unreasonable an approach that would be when compared to `db.Exec`.

Another reason to use `db.Exec` over `db.Query` is when you don't care about the returned result, when all you need is to execute the query and check if there was an error or not. In such a case you can do this:

```
if _, err := db.Exec(`<my_sql_query>`); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
```

On the other hand, you cannot (you can but you shouldn't) do this:

```
if _, err := db.Query(`<my_sql_query>`); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
```

Doing this, after a short while, your program will panic with an error that says something akin to `too many connections open`. This is because you're discarding the returned `db.Rows` value without first making the mandatory `Close` call on it, and so you end up with the number of open connections going up and eventually hitting the server's limit.

---

#### "or prepared statements in Golang?":

I don't think the book you've cited is correct. At least to me it looks like whether or not a `db.Query` call creates a new prepared statement every time is dependent upon the driver you are using.

See for example these two sections of `queryDC` (an unexported method called by `db.Query`): [without prepared statement](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/database/sql/sql.go#L1541-L1555) and [with prepared statement](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/database/sql/sql.go#L1558-L1585).

Regardless of whether the book is correct or not a `db.Stmt` created by `db.Query` would be, unless there is some internal caching going on, thrown away after you close the returned `Rows` object. If you instead manually call `db.Prepare` and then cache and reuse the returned `db.Stmt` you can potentially improve the performance of the queries that need to be executed often.

To understand how a prepared statement can be used to optimize performance you can take a look at the official documentation: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-prepare.html

Comment: Thanks for adding the new part. So this prepare how do you normally cache it? Can you give an example of it. Also I understand that the plan can change how to know when to cache a performant plan?

Comment: @commonSenseCode If I have a query that I know I'll execute often and I believe a prepared statement would be more optimal then I just prepare the statement at the program's start up and keep it in memory for the whole of the program's life, either in a map of statements or as an exported variable... I don't know if this is a good or bad approach but it worked just fine in my case... I haven't yet worked on a project where too many such statements would become a problem by eating up all the memory or anything.