# pq: sorry, too many clients already

Tags: postgresql, go

I am getting `pq: sorry, too many clients already` error when I am calling the `GetMessages()` multiple times.

Please find the updated code:

`main()` code

```
func main() {
  dbConn, err := InitDB()
  if err != nil {
    Log.Error("Connection Error: ", err.Error())
    return
  }
  defer dbConn.Close()
  go run()
  var input string
  fmt.Scanln(&input)
}
```

Database connection code is:

```
func InitDB()(*sql.DB, error) {
  connectionString := fmt.Sprintf("user=%v password='%v' dbname=%v sslmode=disable", USER, PASSWORD, DATABASE)
  db, err = sql.Open(DRIVER, connectionString)
  return db, err
}
```

`run` goroutine:

```
func run() {
  for {
    messages, err := GetMessages()
    if err != nil {
      Log.Error("Connection Error: ", err.Error())
      return
    }
    log.Info(messages)
  }
}
```

`GetMessages()` function code:

```
func GetMessages() (messages []string, err error) {
    rows, err := db.Query(`SELECT message1, message2, message3, message4, message5,
            message6, message7, message8, message9, message10, message11, message12, message13, 
            message14, message15, message16, message17, message18, message19, message20, message21,
            message22, message23, message24, message25, message26, message27, message28, message29,
            message30, message31, message32, message33, message34, message35, message36, message37,
            message38, message39, message40, message41, message42, message43, message44, message45,
            message46, message47, message48 FROM table1 WHERE id=1`)

    if err != nil {
        Log.Error("Query error", err)
        return messages, err
    }

    var pointers []interface{}
    defer rows.Close()

    for rows.Next() {
        pointers = make([]interface{}, 48)
        messages = make([]string, 48)
        for i, _ := range pointers {
            pointers[i] = &messages[i]
        }
        err = rows.Scan(pointers...)
        if err != nil {
            Log.Error("Failed to scan row", err)
            return messages, err
        }
    }

    return messages, nil
}
```

I checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47706147/how-to-reuse-a-single-postgres-db-connection-for-row-inserts-in-go/47711577#47711577) answer and I have used `scan` but still it isn't working

**UPDATE**

Issue was in another function. I was using `db.Query` without closing the returned `rows` object and was repeatedly calling that function. I've updated my code; used `db.Exec` instead of `db.Query` and it's working now. Thank you so much [@mkopriva](https://stackoverflow.com/users/965900/mkopriva) for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50666083/4596814) answer. :)

Comment: Your `GetMessages` code looks fine to me. Where and how many times are you executing the connection code?

Comment: I am calling connection only once from another function. `db` is global variable of type `*sql.DB`

Comment: ... although not related to the issue, the `WHERE id=1` suggests that you're selecting a single row and if that's the case i would recommend you use `db.QueryRow` instead of `db.Query`. (https://play.golang.com/p/pMsuG2alB1v)

Comment: Check what the `max_connection` setting of your postgres server is. ([click here if you don't know how](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8288860/965900)) Also check the number of already existing connections by using `SELECT COUNT(*) from pg_stat_activity;` and/or try inspecting the connections with `SELECT * FROM pg_stat_activity;` during the execution of your go app.

Comment: Tried `db.QueryRow` but no luck. Will try `SELECT * FROM pg_stat_activity;` and let you know the output

Comment: How are you deploying this? Is it possible that there are MANY instances of your code running?

Comment: I wonder what the full function that makes the connection looks like. Because you have a deferred connection close in it, so if that function returned your connection would be closed, but if it does not return, I wonder if it might be opening more and more connections in a loop somewhere

Comment: Are you calling `GetMessages` concurrently?

Comment: @MadWombat Please check the updated code. I am deferring the `db.Close` in `main`.

Comment: @KavehShahbazian, No, I am not calling `GetMessages` concurrently

Comment: The code in the question is incomplete or inconsistent.  The `GetMessages` function uses package-level variable `db`,  but you don't show how the variable set.  The `main` function assigns a database connection to local variable `dbConn`,  but that variable is only used to close the connection.

Comment: start your database connection once. and pass  it using a pointer to all your functions. you are creating many connections and that's why you get this warning.

Comment: Consider answering your own question with your solution and marking it as correct. It'll give you some points and remove the lingering question from the unanswered section :)

Answer (score 4):

Try setting [SetMaxOpenConns](https://pkg.go.dev/database/sql#DB.SetMaxOpenConns). The default is 0 (unlimited). This may be causing the issue. It would help if you also had [SetConnMaxLifetime](https://pkg.go.dev/database/sql#DB.SetConnMaxLifetime); otherwise, Postgres will start holding connections longer, and you will notice an increase in memory usage.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem with my postgres / golang project.

Eventually, this example worked flawlessly, without "eating" any DB connections:

```
// example params
firstName := "Jeremy"
lastName := "Baker"

// setup statement
stmt, err := db.Prepare(
    `INSERT INTO user (
        firstname,
        lastname) VALUES($1, $2)
        RETURNING id`) // id is the primary key of table: user
if err != nil {
    return err
}
defer stmt.Close()

// execute statement
var userID string
err = stmt.QueryRow(
    firstName,
    lastName).Scan(&userID)
if err != nil {
    return err
}
```