# When returning data on an insert or update, do I still need to use `Exec`?

Tags: sql, go

According to [Go Database SQL](http://go-database-sql.org/modifying.html), it says to use `Exec` for modifying data, and `Query` is bad because the underlying connection is kept open until `Rows.Close()` is called. However, there are two cases I can think of that asks what the correct pattern is.

1) Using `sql.Tx` for multiple updates, which will hold the connection until the `Tx.Rollback` or `Tx.Commit`. In this case would it matter?

2) Returning data on an Update, Insert or Delete (especially when using a non-int-based row ID, like UUID). In this case, `QueryRow` seems appropriate, especially since it returns `Row` which doesn't have a `Close` just `Scan`. However, a Tx could be opened to write and then immediately read, but this is often a lot of extra work.

Am I missing something with these two cases?

I'm using Postgres, but from what I'm reading about Go's DB integration, the database implementation shouldn't matter in most cases.

Comment: I've read this question, but it doesn't really answer my question or address my cases: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50664648/why-even-use-db-exec-or-prepared-statements-in-golang

Comment: Not a go programmer, but it looks like the docs are just saying that query returns an object that you need to do something with (close) and never ignore... Nothing specific about why doing updates in query is actually bad.

Answer (score 2):

**TLDR**: There's nothing wrong with using `db.Query` or `db.QueryRow` with `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, or `DELETE`. It is actually the right tool for the job if your SQL commands contain the `RETURNING` clause.

---

**2)** is, in a way, already answered in the linked tutorial by way of actually *excluding* your proposed scenario, since it is talking *explicitly* about cases where you do not care about the returned rows and you therefore choose to assign the returned value to the blank identifier.

> **What if you don’t care about the result?** What if you just want to
>   execute a statement and check if there were any errors, but ignore the
>   result? Wouldn’t the following two statements do the same thing?
>
> ```
> _, err := db.Exec("DELETE FROM users")  // OK
> _, err := db.Query("DELETE FROM users") // BAD
> ```
>
> The answer is no. They do **not** do the same thing, and you **should never
>   use `Query()` like this**. The `Query()` will return a `sql.Rows`, which
>   reserves a database connection until the `sql.Rows` is closed.

The statement *"... you should never use Query() like this ..."* does not refer to `db.Query` being used with `DELETE`, `UPDATE`, or `INSERT`, instead it states, and correctly so, that you should never call `Query` and assign its result to `_`, i.e. you should never do `_, err := db.Query("...`, whatever the sql command is.

Note that the same applies to `QueryRow`, i.e. you should never discard the returned `sql.Row` value or in any other way omit calling its `Scan` method. This is because `sql.Row` is just a simple wrapper around `sql.Rows` and its `Scan` method closes the underlying `sql.Rows` before it returns ([link](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/a2f5d644d3a2903a82e527e3bca2c4bdff1d0750/src/database/sql/sql.go#L3122)).

**1)** As far as I understand, all the above still holds even for transactions. If you have an `sql.Rows` instance, created by an `sql.Tx`, and that `sql.Rows` instance hasn't yet been closed, the `sql.Tx` itself will be prevented from closing ([link](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/a2f5d644d3a2903a82e527e3bca2c4bdff1d0750/src/database/sql/sql.go#L1966)). That is, make sure that when you use `tx.Query` you close the returned rows, and when you use `tx.QueryRow` you call the returned row's `Scan` method.

Comment: "... in a way, already answered in the linked tutorial by way of actually excluding your proposed scenario...", it could be interpreted that way, but with regard to development, I don't often rely on lack of information as tacit acceptance. :grin:

Comment: Nice highlight on the example code ignoring the returned `Rows` variable. i didn't pick up on that. Also nice comment around the Transaction being held open. I didn't realize that either, and very glad I mentioned this case as well.